# How can I make my app to fetch (transactional) SMS when it is neither running in background nor foreground?

Tags: android

I have an app which fetches (reads) SMSes when it is running in foreground or background. However, it does not fetch SMSes when it is killed/ stopped. How can I make it to read SMSes even when the app is closed/ not in use. (The way Truecaller reads SMSes even when it is not running)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on an Sms app so firstly you have to make your app as default app then you can directly receive the message in your app.
You must have to implement the broadcast receiver in your app and once you make your app as default SMS app your broadcast receiver will be called and now you have to receive the message and write into the DB.

Comment: Shubham, I just want the app to read transactional SMSes, not to be as a default SMS app.  Like how Walnut app reads transactional SMSes. Is it possible?